# How to delete records from the target table which is older than 4 years

Tags: sql, mapping, workflow, informatica

I am new to Informatica. How to develop a mapping where a delete step should be added to delete all the records from the target older than 4 years?
source and target are both tables

Answer (score 0):

In your source qualifier just query the table for records older than 4 years and then link the PK to the target via a delete strategy

Comment: can you please tell what will be the query in the delete strategy?

Comment: There is no “query” in a delete strategy component. You put the query in the source qualifier or you could use a filter component. You just query for (or filter in) the records you want to delete - exactly what that query should be, only you will know as we don’t know your table structure, how to identify the age of records, etc

Answer (score 0):

Reading the data with `Source Qualifier` from database to Informatica just to flag them for delete operation is one option. Mapping should look like:

```
Source->Source Qualifier->Update Strategy->Target
```

But it really sounds bad, since you can read nothing and just use Post-SQL target property to perform the delete operation without having literally any data sent across the network.

Comment: If I use update strategy, can you please tell what my query should be like to delete records older than 4 years ?

Comment: Just as commented by NickW: use a filter in your SQ to get just the 4 years old rows.